# Emulating YouTube Mini Player in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, youtube

In the YouTube app, I'm able to continue watching videos via a mini-player in the very bottom right-hand corner (see video below entitled "The Chainsmokers") that's layered atop all other view controllers as I navigate the app. No matter which page I'm on, I can watch the video in the mini player.

If you drag up from the mini player, the video's entire view controller will appear. But it's always atop other pages. I'm trying to understand how to copy this method using Swift so I can watch the video from any page.

The way my app is structured is through a `UIPageViewController`. I'm embedding three unique navigation controllers (for swipe nav purposes (see code below)). I want to understand how to utilize the mini-player. In YouTube, is that like a mini modal VC? How is it structurally laid out, and if you know, how can I incorporate that into my current layout?

```
class PageViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

    private var pages: [UINavigationController]!

    private var currentPageIndex: Int!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
            self.dataSource = self
            self.delegate = self

            self.pages = [
                self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Nav1") as! UINavigationController,
                self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Nav2") as! UINavigationController,
                self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Nav3") as! UINavigationController
            ]

            (self.pages[0].topViewController as! Nav1).parentPageViewController = self
            (self.pages[1].topViewController as! Nav2).parentPageViewController = self
            (self.pages[2].topViewController as! Nav3).parentPageViewController = self


            self.currentPageIndex = 1
            let startingViewController = self.pages[1] as UINavigationController
            self.setViewControllers([startingViewController], direction: .Forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
}
func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        let index = (self.pages as NSArray).indexOfObject(viewController)
        self.currentPageIndex = index

        // if currently displaying last view controller, return nil to indicate that there is no next view controller
        return (self.currentPageIndex == self.pages.count - 1 ? nil : self.pages[self.currentPageIndex + 1])
    }
func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        let index = (self.pages as NSArray).indexOfObject(viewController)
        self.currentPageIndex = index

        // if currently displaying first view controller, return nil to indicate that there is no previous view controller
        return (index == 0 ? nil : self.pages[index - 1])
    }
func displayPageForIndex(index: Int, animated: Bool = true) {
        assert(index >= 0 && index < self.pages.count, "Error: Attempting to display a page for an out of bounds index")

        // nop if index == self.currentPageIndex
        if self.currentPageIndex == index { return }

        if index < self.currentPageIndex {
            self.setViewControllers([self.pages[index]], direction: .Reverse, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else if index > self.currentPageIndex {
            self.setViewControllers([self.pages[index]], direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        self.currentPageIndex = index
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: I would take a "higher" approach by adding a UIWindow that hides it's bottom contents as well as mini-mizes as you move it downward and reverses the process when it goes upwards. Then the "catalog" behind it would be non the wiser and just communicate whenever the user tapped on a new "catalog item".

Comment: I'm still confused on the hierarchy of views. The full song page is its own view controller. But when minimized, is it still a view controller or a custom view? Can I make that sit atop a PageViewController's view so it's accessible from all pages?

Comment: I don't even need to minimize it. If I can just pass the `UIWebView` from one VC to the `UIPageViewController`'s view and make it accessible from all pages, that's A-OK with me

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is quite easy to do. You will subclass UIWindow, add a mini-player view and make sure it is alway at the top of view hierarchy. First in your `AppDelegate` add this code to overwrite your window:

```
/*!
 *  Subclassing UIWindow
 */
-(UIWindow *)window
{
    static YourWindow *customWindow = nil;
    if (!customWindow) customWindow = [[YourWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    return customWindow;
}
```

And now in `YourWindow` class, add the `miniPlayer`:

```
-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    [self addMiniPlayer];
}

-(void)addMiniPlayer
{
    UIView *miniPlayer = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,100)]; //change to your frame here
    [self addSubview:miniPlayer];
    miniPlayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    self.miniPlayer = miniPlayer;
}

-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    [self bringSubviewToFront:self.miniPlayer];

    // You would like to update your miniplayer frame here.
    //CGRect frame = self.miniPlayer.frame;
    //frame.origin.x = self.frame.size.width - frame.size.width - 5;
    //frame.origin.y = 70;
    //self.appInfoLabel.frame = frame;
}
```

Now it is your job to adjust the behavior of the `miniPlayer`. You can access it from `AppDelegate`, something like this: `self.window.miniPlayer`

UPDATED: Here is an example written by Swift: https://github.com/sahara108/TestCustomWindow

Comment: I wrote it in objc because I currently use Objc, but if you need Swift version, it is easy to convert to Swift.

Comment: Can you elaborate on `YourWindow`? What is it, what am I doing with it? And what is my `YourWindow` class where I add the mini player? Is that a custom class in my app del?

Comment: It is subclass of `UIWindow`. Look at my answer, I demonstrate a way to add the mini player whenever the window is loaded. Give it a try with a frame and background, you will see a small view is alway in top of your view.

Comment: Yes but I don't actually understand what `YourWindow` is when I'm declaring `static YourWindow *customWindow` and in my `YourWindow` class. What is my `YourWindow` class? This is why I'm asking for elaboration.

Comment: By default, all of iOS application will create a window when it launched. And then you will create your view controller and add its view to this window by doing `self.window.rootViewController = vc` in `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOption`. So that the code `static YourWindow *customWindow...` will replace the default instance of `UIWindow` with an instance of `YourWindow`. The purpose of this is that you can able to add your `miniPlayer` directly into your window and make it is the topmost view.

Comment: Sorry, which view controller am I creating? If I'm instantiating all of my navigation controllers in a page view controller, as I've posed in my question, am I creating the page view controller and adding that view to the window?

Comment: Yes, you are creating the page view controller and add its view to the window. When you instantiate a navigation controller, you are adding it over the page view controller view.

Comment: I'm confused as to how to create the `UIPageViewController` within `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. I have `var vc = PageViewController(); 
        
        self.window!.rootViewController = vc`. Also, I still don't understand the `YourWindow` class.

Comment: You don't need to change any line of your code. What you need to do is create a new class named `YourWindow`. Try it and use the code in my answer, you will see a small red view alway in the top of your view. If you still don't know how to implement, you can comment here and I will try to give an example.

Comment: I'd appreciate an example. It's tough to implement while trying to translate to Swift. Apologies for being new to Swift.

Comment: This is so great. How can I detect programmatically from another class whether the button is hidden or not? For instance, something like `if playerIsHidden { // do this }` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84759/discussion-between-sahara108-and-dperk).

Comment: Last q: is there a way to access the mini player in a different size and display it on one view controller in particular?

Comment: Yes, of course. You can show the mini player in view will appear, hide it in view will disappear. You can also write an api to change its frame the way I did for playerIsHidden

Comment: Got it. But the video zoom scale doesn't change. Can I change that in the middle of a video playing?

Comment: It is a difference issue. I think there is a lot of topic about it here. Or you can post a question with your code so the others can help.

Comment: I got it. You've gone above and beyond! Thank you!

Comment: Hi @sahara108 How to apply all orientation to added player view only and all the of the view-controllers are in portrait mode? I will really appreciate your input here.

Comment: @VishwanathDeshmukh hey, I also did it before by manual rotating the view base on the device orientation. I couldn't recall the code but you can try to google it.